# SF report formula - date

Tags: custom-reports, function

I would like to add additional column in report where function will be checking if the condition is met.
Formula should check if order priority is:

- High and then if creation date of order is less or equal 1 day
  or
- Normal and then if creation date of order is less or equal 36 days
  if true than answer "in time", if not than answer "Overdue".

In excel formula looks:
`=IF(OR(AND(F2="High";TODAY()-G2<=1);(AND(F2="Normal";TODAY()-G2<=36)));"In time";"Overdue")`
but I can't do that in Salesforce. Is it possible?

I tried something like that:

```
IF(
    OR(
        AND(
            WorkOrder.Priority="High",
            TODAY()-WorkOrder.CreatedDate:UNIQUE<=1
        ),
        AND(
            WorkOrder.Priority="Normal",
            TODAY()-WorkOrder.CreatedDate:UNIQUE<=36
       )
    ),
    "In time",
    "Overdue"
)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly? Are you getting an error when you try to save the formula ([edit] your question to include the error, verbatim, if you are)? Is it not producing the correct result ([edit] your question to give some examples of inputs, your expected output, and the actual output if so)?

Comment: The first odd thing I see is the `UNIQUE` bit. That sounds inappropriate in this situation. That would be used in something like a summary formula (that summarizes the entire report instead of working on a single row). If you had, say, 5 WorkOrders with 4 different CreatedDates, the `:UNIQUE` counter would return 4. `A Date - <some integer>` would give you a date `<some integer>` days in the past. My best guess with the details you've given so far is that this should be a row-level formula (and get that `:UNIQUE` out of there) instead of a summary formula. Giving us more details would help.

Comment: Error appears "Warning Incorrect parameter type for operator '<='. Expected Date, received Number".

Comment: When I removed ":UNIQUE" then appers error "Field WorkOrder.CreatedDate does not exist. Check spelling."

Comment: I just want show lines where I have time on processing and overdue lines.